# Split Up Big Polygon Into Smaller Ones By Condition

Tags: algorithm, split, leaflet, polygon, postgis

I have some big Polygon. Within it collection of leaflet layers (points). Every point have some numeric property. What I want is split up big Polygon into smaller ones. 
Every smaller polygon should contain points with ~equal (+-200 ok) sum of points properties. On the left side of my example page I added image of desirable result.
[Here is my simplified example](https://codepen.io/ckpunmep/pen/POJLNN) with sufficient code and comments.

1. So my first step is find some start point within big Polygon. It's should be point near Polygon edge - the northernmost point for example.

   ```
   var nothernmostPoint= 0;
   var nothernmostLayer= 0;
   L.geoJSON(features, {
       pointToLayer: function (feature) {
           return L.circleMarker(feature.geometry.coordinates.reverse(), defaultPointStyle);
       },
       onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
           if (feature.geometry.coordinates[0] > nothernmostPoint) {
               nothernmostPoint = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
               nothernmostLayer = feature;
           }
       }
   }).addTo(map);
   ```

---

2. Second step is to find next nearest point(s) to my start point.

   ```
    var geoJ = L.GeometryUtil.nClosestLayers(map, features, nothernmostLayer.geometry.coordinates, 5);
   ```

---

3. Then sum up their properties. If sum is smaller than needed I go to step 2 and repeat, if sum is satisfy condition then I draw polygon with chosen points inside it and find nearest point to my last point and repeat search for points for the next smaller polygon.

---

My current difficulty is to find nearest point(s) to my start point. For that purpose I use **GeometryUtil Leaflet plugin**. Red dots are points that **GeometryUtil** found as nearest to my start point (the green one). It's certainly not what I was expected. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should use different algorithm and/or tool for that task? Any useful suggestions greatly appreciated.

If it may help - all that data I store in **PostgreSQL** with **PostGIS** extension. Maybe this can be done on database level.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is rather small, you can go brute force way in PostGIS:

- for each point, generate N points that represent the 'weight', using `select geom, generate_series(0, weight)`;
- decide on number of clusters you want to get, approximately `sum(weight)/desired_sum`;
- run K-Means clustering on dataset, https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_ClusterKMeans.html
- draw a polygon around each cluster using ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)).